# ADC TP filter for current measurement (BLDC motor application)

Tags: motor-controller

I’m in the process of designing the current measurement for a motor control application (3-Phase). Now, the motor current is controlled @10kHz and the PWM is at 20kHz, so the cut-off frequency should be bigger than the 10kHz, let's say 15kHz.

Now comes the problem with aliasing. The current can be measured only at a specific point (SVPWM) and so only with the PWM frequency of 20kHz. According to the Nyquist theorem, fs > 2fmax, so the current should probably be sampled with 50kHz or more if I choose a cut-off frequency of around 15kHz, but this is not possible as described above.

What can be done about that and how is this normally solved in BLDC motor control application?

Comment: What does your current waveform look like if you captured it on an analogue oscilloscope?

Comment: Sinusoidal, FOC is used with SVPWM. There is some deadtime in the current, but it does not look very different from sinusoidal

Comment: So, if it looks sinusoidal at 10 kHz, then sample at around 25 kHz.

Comment: The problem is, the sampling is synchronized with the PWM (as done for SVPWM) and this seems a very common problem. I have seen many controllers, where the PWM is 20kHz and also the control loop is 20kHz, so there should theoretically be a lot of aliasing in nearly all industrial controllers. It seems there is a trick that I don't see here.

Comment: You are synchronously measuring the amplitude of the value, not the frequency or phase.

Comment: Yes, that it true. So as long as the current measurement phase frequency is not faster than half the sampling rate, there should be no aliasing, right?